# How to copy specific files from the sub-folders to a new folder in python?

Tags: python, dataset, classification, directory-structure

I have a folder with several sub-folders, each containing the same number of files (here it is 7). The code that I use at the present copies all the files from the different sub-folders within a main folder, to another new folder.

```
import os
import shutil

src = r'C:\Users\datasets\test\0'
dest = r'C:\Users\datasets\data_new\test\0'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)
        shutil.copy2(filename, dest)
```

I need to modify the code in a way to copy only the last image (i.e. the 7th image in this case) from each sub-folder (windows file arrangement) to a new folder.

Comment: Basically you just sort the "files" because the order isn't guaranteed and take the last item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob

src = r'C:\temp\datasets\test\0'
dest = r'C:\temp\datasets\data_new\test\0'

for base, dirs, _ in os.walk(src):
    for path in dirs:
        files = sorted(glob(os.path.join(base, path, '*')))
        if len(files) == 0:
            continue
        file = files[-1]
        filename = os.path.join(path, file)
        shutil.copyfile(filename, dest)
```

Comment: Per @MichaelButscher's comment, you may want to wrap the glob in a call to sorted() in order to make this more platform independent. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: `files[len(files) - 1]` can be written as `files[-1]`. Maybe a check that `files` isn't empty may also be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I edited my answer to account for your points. Thanks! I'm just continuing when we hit an empty folder rather than doing any exception handling, although I could see the virtue of using a try block instead.